# creating new row on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html table with one or more row. I have 4 columns in my table in that one is a checkbox. Two buttons are there "AddRowAbove" and "AddRowBelow". When a particular checkbox is checked and click a button a new row should be added based on the button name. My code looks like this not sure how to achieve the result.

```js
function addNewRowAbove() {

  alert("actioned !!!");
  var rowNumber = document.getElementById("rowIndex").value;
  var rowNumberNew = parseInt(rowNumber) - 1;
  alert(rowNumber + " - " + rowNumberNew);
  var newRow = $('<tr/>').attr('id', 'row' + rowNumberNew);
  newRow.html('<td><input type="checkbox" name="radio1" id="radio' + rowNumberNew + '"></input><input type="hidden" id="rowIndex' + rowNumberNew + '" value="' + rowNumberNew + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="empid" id="empid' + rowNumberNew + '"></input></td><td><input type="text" name="empfname" id="empfname' + rowNumberNew + '"></input></td><td><input type="text" name="emplname" id="emplname' + rowNumberNew + '"></input></td>');
  $('#maintable tbody').append(newRow);
}

function addNewRowBelow() {

  alert("actioned !!!");
  var rowNumber = document.getElementById("rowIndex").value;
  var rowNumberNew = parseInt(rowNumber) + 1;
  alert(rowNumber + " - " + rowNumberNew);
  var newRow = $('<tr/>').attr('id', 'row' + rowNumberNew);
  newRow.html('<td><input type="checkbox" name="radio1" id="radio' + rowNumberNew + '"></input><input type="hidden" id="rowIndex' + rowNumberNew + '" value="' + rowNumberNew + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="empid" id="empid' + rowNumberNew + '"></input></td><td><input type="text" name="empfname" id="empfname' + rowNumberNew + '"></input></td><td><input type="text" name="emplname" id="emplname' + rowNumberNew + '"></input></td>');
  $('#maintable tbody').append(newRow);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <table id="maintable" width="50%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="#729111 1px solid">
    <tr>
      <th align="center">Select</th>
      <th align="center">Employee ID</th>
      <th align="center">First Name</th>
      <th align="center">Last Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="radio" id="radio"></input><input type="hidden" id="rowIndex" value="1" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="empid"></input>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="empfname"></input>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="emplname"></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="radio1" id="radio1"></input><input type="hidden" id="rowIndex" value="2" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="empid1"></input>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="empfname1"></input>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="emplname1"></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td> <input type="submit" name="AddRowAbove" value="AddRowAbove" onclick="addNewRowAbove()"></td>
      <td> <input type="submit" name="AddRowBelow" value="AddRowBelow" onclick="addNewRowBelow()"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: First,`id` is unique, so you should not set different element with the same `id` as `id="rowIndex"`.
Second, your table do not have `<tbody>`. Kindly add it.

Comment: what's the reference for above and below? the checkbox at which user has clicked?

Comment: @MrNeo I am not sure how to get the row number of each row. Please suggest a best method.

Comment: Dherya yes, checkbox should be clicked. Validation is not added now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added `var selectedRow = $( "input:checked" ).parent().parent();` to both of your functions to find the parent row of the checked element, and then used either `$(newRow).insertBefore(selectedRow);` or `$(newRow).insertAfter(selectedRow);` depending on the button clicked.

Hopefully this helps.

**UPDATE:**

In response to comments requesting that the id's of the rows are kept in order even after adding rows dynamically, I've added a  `SortRowIDs()` function which is called at the end of both `addNewRowAbove()` and `addNewRowBelow()`.

This function grabs all of the `<input type="checkbox"/>` tags in the `<table id="maintable"></table>` and then iterates through them using jQuery's `.each()` method. Each checkbox's parent row is then assigned an Id based on its order in the table. I also added a few comments in the code so that it is easier to follow.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

  function SortRowIDs() {
  
    // The code below finds all the <tr> elements in the table WITH checkboxes in them.
    // This way, we skip the first row containing column headers and the last row containing buttons
    
    // We use the jQuery .each() method to iterate through jQuery-object arrays 
    $('#maintable').find('tr > td > input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(index) {
      
      // We assign the parent row of the current checkbox to the variable 'currentRow'
      let currentRow = $(this).parent().parent();
      
      // Here we give the current row an id based on its position in the table
      $(currentRow).attr('id', 'id_' + (index + 1));
      
      // Prints the id's of each row
      console.log('Current row\'s id: ' + $(currentRow).attr('id'));
      
    });
    
    // This prints the id attribute of the selected checkbox's parent row, to show that 
    // the Id's were successfully assigned by the SortRowIDs() function
    console.log('');
    console.log('Selected row\'s id: ' + $( "input:checked" ).parent().parent().attr('id'));
    
  }

  function addNewRowAbove() {
    
    var rowNumber = document.getElementById("rowIndex").value;
    var rowNumberNew = parseInt(rowNumber) - 1;
    
    var newRow = $('<tr/>');
    
    newRow.html('<td><input type="checkbox" name="radio1" id="radio' + rowNumberNew + '" /><input type="hidden" id="rowIndex' + rowNumberNew + '" value="' + rowNumberNew + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="empid" id="empid' + rowNumberNew + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="empfname" id="empfname' + rowNumberNew + '"></input></td><td><input type="text" name="emplname" id="emplname' + rowNumberNew + '"></input></td>');
    
    var selectedRow = $( "input:checked" ).parent().parent();
    
    $(newRow).insertBefore(selectedRow);
    
    SortRowIDs();
  }

  function addNewRowBelow() {

    var rowNumber = document.getElementById("rowIndex").value;
    var rowNumberNew = parseInt(rowNumber) + 1;
    
    var newRow = $('<tr/>');
    
    newRow.html('<td><input type="checkbox" name="radio1" id="radio' + rowNumberNew + '"></input><input type="hidden" id="rowIndex' + rowNumberNew + '" value="' + rowNumberNew + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="empid" id="empid' + rowNumberNew + '"></input></td><td><input type="text" name="empfname" id="empfname' + rowNumberNew + '"></input></td><td><input type="text" name="emplname" id="emplname' + rowNumberNew + '"></input></td>');
    
    var selectedRow = $( "input:checked" ).parent().parent();
    
    $(newRow).insertAfter(selectedRow);
    
    SortRowIDs();
  }
</script>

<form>
  <table id="maintable" width="50%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="#729111 1px solid">
    <tr>
      <th align="center">Select</th>
      <th align="center">Employee ID</th>
      <th align="center">First Name</th>
      <th align="center">Last Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="radio" id="radio"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="rowIndex" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="empid" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="empfname" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="emplname" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="radio1" id="radio1" />
        <input type="hidden" id="rowIndex" value="2" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="empid1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="empfname1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="emplname1" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td> 
        <input type="submit" name="AddRowAbove" value="AddRowAbove" onclick="addNewRowAbove()">
      </td>
      <td> 
        <input type="submit" name="AddRowBelow" value="AddRowBelow" onclick="addNewRowBelow()">
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: I just copied this code and it just blinks on click. But here when I run the code it works !!!!

Comment: Hmm.. did you copy my HTML exactly? I changed some of your code (i.e look at my <input /> tags vs your <input></input> tags) so perhaps some of your code that isn't related to this form is invalid? Are you receiving any console errors?

Comment: Yes, I copied the same and there is no error in console. below are the messages copied from console.                                                HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
File: AddNewRowsIn.html
HTML1527: DOCTYPE expected. Consider adding a valid HTML5 doctype: "<!DOCTYPE html>".
File: AddNewRowsIn.html, Line: 1, Column: 1
DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337
File: AddNewRowsIn.html

Comment: Okay, so there seem to be some other issues in your HTML. The HTML1300 warning means that "A new page was navigated to, or the current page was refreshed." and the HTML1527 error indicates that your HTML document doesn't have a valid doctype declaration.. more info regarding these warnings can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh180764%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and you can find out more about valid doctype declaration here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Comment: In the above example each time when a new row added it should update the rownumber dynamically rt ? , how that can be possible?

Comment: Im not quite sure what you're asking, but in the above code each new row is assigned an ID based on the row it was added before/after:                 var newRow = $('<tr/>').attr('id', 'row' + rowNumberNew); this code creates the new row element, and sets its ID to 'rowX' where X is a dynamically created number based on the selected action.

Comment: Let me explain that, In a dynamically generated table I have 5 rows in that each row I have a check box with id  id_1,  id_2,  id_3,  id_4,  id_5. If I wanted to add a row below id_2 then the new row id should become id_3 and then id's followed by that should be updated as id_4, id_5, id_6.

Comment: @JAVA_CAT Ah, I understand. I've updated my answer with a function that will make sure that the row Id's are in order after adding rows to the table. Let me know if it helps

Answer (score 2):

You can use [insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/) to append new row above buttons (give `id="button"` to row content buttons). Try with below solution:

```js
function addNewRowAbove(){

    alert("actioned !!!");
   var rowNumber=document.getElementById("rowIndex").value;
    var rowNumberNew = parseInt(rowNumber)- 1 ;
    alert(rowNumber+" - "+rowNumberNew);
   var newRow = $('<tr/>').attr('id', 'row' + rowNumberNew);
    newRow.html('<td><input type="checkbox" name="radio1" id="radio'+rowNumberNew+'"></input><input type="hidden" id="rowIndex'+rowNumberNew+'" value="'+rowNumberNew+'"/></td><td><input type="text" name="empid" id="empid'+rowNumberNew+'"></input></td><td><input type="text" name="empfname" id="empfname'+rowNumberNew+'"></input></td><td><input type="text" name="emplname" id="emplname'+rowNumberNew+'"></input></td>');
    newRow.insertBefore('#button');
}

function addNewRowBelow(){

    alert("actioned !!!");
   var rowNumber=document.getElementById("rowIndex").value;
    var rowNumberNew = parseInt(rowNumber) + 1 ;
    alert(rowNumber+" - "+rowNumberNew);
   var newRow = $('<tr/>').attr('id', 'row' + rowNumberNew);
    newRow.html('<td><input type="checkbox" name="radio1" id="radio'+rowNumberNew+'"></input><input type="hidden" id="rowIndex'+rowNumberNew+'" value="'+rowNumberNew+'"/></td><td><input type="text" name="empid" id="empid'+rowNumberNew+'"></input></td><td><input type="text" name="empfname" id="empfname'+rowNumberNew+'"></input></td><td><input type="text" name="emplname" id="emplname'+rowNumberNew+'"></input></td>');
        $('#maintable tbody').append(newRow);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
 <table id="maintable" width="50%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  border="#729111 1px solid">
<tr>
                <th align="center">Select</th>
                <th align="center">Employee ID</th>
                <th align="center">First Name</th>
                <th align="center">Last Name</th>
            </tr>
            <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="radio" id="radio"></input><input type="hidden" id="rowIndex" value="1"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="empid"></input></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="empfname"></input></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="emplname"></input></td>
            </tr>
             <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="radio1" id="radio1"></input><input type="hidden" id="rowIndex" value="2"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="empid1"></input></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="empfname1"></input></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="emplname1"></input></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="button"><td></td><td> <input type="submit" name="AddRowAbove" value="AddRowAbove" onclick="addNewRowAbove()"></td><td> <input type="submit" name="AddRowBelow" value="AddRowBelow" onclick="addNewRowBelow()"></td><td></td></tr>
       </table>
  </form>     
</body>

</html>
```